# Linear Response theory

Tags: condensed-matter, complex-numbers, dirac-delta-distributions

I was reading through Lecture of of Prof Patrick Lee on Linear Response Theory. I have found the following relation and could not understand why is it true:
$$\Im \left\{\frac{1}{x + i\eta}\right\} = -\pi \delta \left(x\right)$$
where, $\eta \rightarrow 0$. Can someone explain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The imaginary part of the function $\frac{1}{x+i\eta}$ is $F_\eta(x)=-\frac{\eta}{x^2+\eta^2}$. It satisfies $\int dx F_\eta(x)=-\pi$, and for any (reasonable) function $f(x)$ it can be proven that
$$ \lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}\int dx f(x)F_\eta(x) = -\pi f(0)$$

Therefore the limit of $F_\eta$ when $\eta\rightarrow 0$ has all the properties one would expect from $-\pi \delta(x)$, and thus can be identified.

Comment: Presumably you mean that $F_\eta$ is the imaginary part of $1/x+i\eta$, no?

Comment: Please, add the details of the evaluation of the integral and its limit, since it contains details that can make the answer more clear, clearly stating the assumptions in this calculation